# Transforming XML data to HTML using XSL and Php: only printing xml tags without any formatting

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

I have to transform my xml output to html. I am following a tutorial at [link text](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Transforming_XML_data_to_HTML_using_XSL_and_PHP)  My code is outputting xml tags in a single line without any formatting with text value.I want the output as an HTML unordered list following hierarchical structure of parent child in xml file output.

Here is page output:

```
message msg 1message msg 1-1message msg 1-2message msg 1-2-1message msg 1-2-2message 
msg 1-2-2-1message msg 1-2-2-1-1message msg 1-2-2-1-2
```

& here is page source:

```
<html:ul xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><html:li>message msg 1</html:li>
<html:ul><html:li>message msg 1-1</html:li><html:li>message msg 1-2</html:li><html:ul>
<html:li>message msg 1-2-1</html:li><html:li>message msg 1-2-2</html:li><html:ul>
<html:li>message msg 1-2-2-1</html:li><html:ul><html:li>message msg 1-2-2-1-1</html:li>
<html:li>message msg 1-2-2-1-2</html:li></html:ul></html:ul></html:ul></html:ul></html:ul>
```

Here is my code

```
php file:

<?php
# LOAD XML FILE
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load('messages.xml');

# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load('msg.xsl');
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
?>
```

msg.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="messages">
    <html:ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
    </html:ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message[message]">
    <html:li>message <xsl:value-of select="@msg_id" /></html:li>
    <html:ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
    </html:ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <html:li>message <xsl:value-of select="@msg_id" /></html:li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

messages.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="msg.xsl"?><messages>
    <message msg_id="1" emp_msg="msg 1" parent_msg_id="" parent_msg="" depth="0">
        <message msg_id="2" emp_msg="msg 1-1" parent_msg_id="1" parent_msg="msg 1" depth="1"/>
        <message msg_id="3" emp_msg="msg 1-2" parent_msg_id="1" parent_msg="msg 1" depth="1">
            <message msg_id="4" emp_msg="msg 1-2-1" parent_msg_id="3" parent_msg="msg 1-2" depth="2"/>
            <message msg_id="5" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2" parent_msg_id="3" parent_msg="msg 1-2" depth="2">
                <message msg_id="6" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2-1" parent_msg_id="5" parent_msg="msg 1-2-2" depth="3">
                    <message msg_id="7" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2-1-1" parent_msg_id="6" parent_msg="msg 1-2-2-1" depth="4"/>
                    <message msg_id="8" emp_msg="msg 1-2-2-1-2" parent_msg_id="6" parent_msg="msg 1-2-2-1" depth="4"/>
                </message>
            </message>
        </message>
    </message>
</messages>
```

Comment: Is the XML file not valid because of a cut & paste error or is that what you're trying to transform? - last line "</message" should be "</messages>"

Comment: What does your output look like, and how do you want it to look?

Comment: @Chris Bentley, that is cut & paste mistake only. I fixed the error, it was due to using 'loadXML' instead of 'load' to load xml doc. Though its not showing results, just outputting tags. I updated my question.

Comment: That's not the output I get here. Did you look at the page source?

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, it is displaying all xml tags with numbers added to it. Numbers probably it get from xml output as its a part of it. I added output to OP. Actually I want the output as an HTML unordered list following  hierarchical structure of parent child in xml file output. & it should contain values of 'msg_id' & 'emp_msg'.

Comment: @Ignacio, I think that's is out put as when I change the content to display from 'msg_id' that you put to 'msg', it displays the messages. I mean added with xml tags. I put the source of page in to OP. Can you drop the XHTML elements as Martin mentioned. Also one more thing is that I need to both 'msg_id' & 'emp_msg' to be displayed.

Comment: Wich of these two we should consider as duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340173/how-could-i-edit-this-xsl-file-so-that-it-works-for-all-browser

Comment: @Alejandro, its same here again. I posted this question to ask about what problem in my xml transformation. & Other question is I was trying to remove xhtml fragments from xsl & it was not successful, so I asked what wrong with what I did to remove xhtml fragments.Off course will appear same at all places as its what I am building but I am addressing something else about same part of a code

Comment: @XCeptable: The problem is the same, as is the same the answer. You are nothing more than refrasing the question. You ask: How transform this XML to this HTML. I've told you: the problem is in your stylesheet, do it this way. Then you asked in other place: How edit your stylesheet correcting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet does not output HTML but rather an XHTML fragment, and that in a way (with qualified names) that you need to serve it as application/xml to a browser (like Mozilla, Opera, Safari, IE 9, but not IE 6-8) that understands that content type.

So make sure you do something like

```
  header('Content-Type: application/xml');
```

before sending the content to the browser. Or drop any XHTML namespace and any prefixes from the result elements, then the XSLT stylesheet outputs an HTML fragment many more browsers can parse and understand as text/html and render it as you want.

Comment: header is a PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php so assuming you use PHP you need to make the sbown function call in your PHP code before sending any contents to the browser, so make sure you put it before the print statement.

Comment: @XCeptable: You can get rid of the `html` namespace by removing the `xmlns:html` attribute and removing the `html:` in front of each element. Make sure that you leave the `xsl` namespace alone, since it's required in order to make the XSLT work.

Comment: you are grate :), thanx a thousands times

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, thanX a thousands times ignacio, your xsl is working very nice :) But still there is some work to do. As I used this xml by saving it locally, But in application, its generated dynamically by php code, so How do I do it there. Should I replace the 'loadXML' part with code that generates result set in xml, get that output in xml & use? OR should I put a new question for that?

Answer (score 0):

To be crossbrowser, I would use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>
    <xsl:template match="messages">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="message[1]">
        <ul>
            <xsl:call-template name="makeListItem"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="message" name="makeListItem">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('message ',@msg_id)" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<ul>
 <li>message 1
  <ul>
   <li>message 2</li>
   <li>message 3
    <ul>
     <li>message 4</li>
     <li>message 5
      <ul>
       <li>message 6
        <ul>
         <li>message 7</li>
         <li>message 8</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Render as:

- message 1

  - message 2
  - message 3

    - message 4
    - message 5

      - message 6

        - message 7
        - message 8

**Note**: HTML DOCTYPE, no namespace. Also other approach to hierarchie processing with fine grained traversal.

Comment: @Alejandro, I used this but it prints simple xml without any formating

Comment: @XCeptable: Very strange! I've tested with your exact PHP code, your exact input sample and my stylesheet.

Comment: @XCeptable: That is because you are not ussing your exact PHP code as in question: you have added the Content Type header as suggested by @Martin Honnen, or you have added this Content Type in .htaccess file, or what ever post processor. That message is from browser and it means simple: "This is an XML document without CSS nor XSLT stylesheet, so I (browser) am going to use my own stylesheet"

Comment: @Alejandro, you are right, I have no words to thank as it all of a sudden make everything working as yours do not use any kind of headers. thanks a thousands again

Comment: @Alejandro, <xsl:value-of select="concat('',@msg_id,@emp_msg)" />      If I want to print one tag say msg_id only in root but not in child then how to do this ?