# array fo data to load to a xsl file

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, xslt

I have two xsl pages. One is taking data from a service and show only some data. I have put an anchor to each data, when clicked it, it redirect to other xsl page. I am passing an array to the other xsl. I have no idea how to show those data in that xsl. I have tried it with a url as below which was a success,

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$type = @$_REQUEST['angelID'];
$id = @$_REQUEST['angelType'];

$url = 'http://localhost/level5/level4.php?id='.$id.'&type='.$type;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl = new DOMDocument();

$xsl->load( 'detail.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xslt->importStylesheet( $xsl );
print $xslt->transformToXML($doc); 

?>
```

But I want to replace the url with the data I send from the previous page.I don't want to call the service again as above.Below is how I send data ,

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Angel">
    <div>
     <xsl:value-of select="@type" /> 
<xsl:variable name="type">
    <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
    </xsl:variable>
    <a width="160" height="200" href="showInDetailXslt.php?angelType={$type}">
    <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://localhost/level5/images/',service/images)"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 </img>
 </a>
```

I don't know how to get it php and show in the other xsl page

Comment: Did you tried this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881515/save-and-display-a-xml-file-created-by-transforming-values-of-another-xml-using _____ http://code.runnable.com/UnDVmork4dZtAABB/how-to-transform-xml-to-html-using-php-for-xsl-and-xslt _____ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335513/transforming-xml-data-to-html-using-xsl-and-php-only-printing-xml-tags-without I hope this might help you

Comment: Also check this - http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/xsl.html

Comment: I have checked it. It is passing an xml to dom document. Here I have passed array from the previous page